# Viewport and render result different

Tags: rendering

The emission map and the glass are visible in the viewport but not in the final render.

Do you know why?

Render:
[image: render]

Viewport:
[image: viewport]

Comment: why did you send the .blend1 ?

Comment: Because i tried to share also textures. Is it visible?

Comment: why did you revert my approved edit ?? "emission maps" and "glass" means nothing ?!

Comment: why had the images been removed? Messed up?

Answer (score 3):

Before posting these, check your Outliner. Your `Collection 1` is enabled for render but not for viewport.

[image]

Comment: thank you I didn't sleep yesterday i wasted a lot of time. Sorry for that

Comment: If this fixed your problem, please do Accept this answer to mark it solved

Comment: It might be not that obvious for new Blender users. There are objects *Collection 1* that are hidden in viewport but are still rendered. The eye icon hides objects in the viewport, the camera icon hides it in the render. If you disable the collection by clicking the checkbox it will be hidden in the viewport and render as well.

Comment: Indeed. I had assumed OP is familiar enough with Blender that they could have spotted it themselves. This assumption was based on the scale and quality of the Blender file as well as the amount of non-default settings that had been set.

One more note for OP: Instead of MixRGB'ing two Principled shaders, you should instead MixRGB or lerp the settings. This should drastically improve performance.